# Create PDF containing an editable field using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, npm

I am using [jsPDF](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/) to build a PDF in my project. I need to have an editable field in the generated PDF and the user should be able to save the entered value either when downloading or printing the PDF. Right now the value is not saved and I haven't found a library that has this feature.

Does anyone know a good library for JavaScript that has this functionality?

Comment: Wouldn't it be much easier to present the pdf in the browser as html, add a text input. When the user hits print, the PDF gets printed with the value in the text box?

Comment: PDF -> Portable Display Format. A PDF is moreorless just a photo version of a document. That's why they're not editable (without the use of GIMP or Photoshop etc.). No language (that I'm aware of) has the functionality you are after. As Ilyas suggested, create the input **before** generation and display that value in the PDF

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs PDF documents can contain actual text and input forms, not just images.  I've never tried this from Javascript, but for example, this PDF library for Java and .NET and others, contains ability to create such forms: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-form-examples

Comment: @NicholasSmith that's not what my comment says - I'm saying it's a photo version of a document, not that it only contains photos ...

Comment: @NicholasSmith also clicked and first .pdf file I clicked doesn't load?

Comment: @treyBake Exactly like NicholasSmith is saying there are such libraries for Java so I assumed it would exist for JavaScript as well.

Comment: @SaraAmani except.. the linked one doesn't work ...

Comment: @treyBake I am not referring to the link he sent, I have actually seen it being done in a project I was in.

Comment: @SaraAmani I honestly have never come across anything that edits PDF live.

Comment: @treyBake Okay, I appreciate your help anyway, thanks!